# VBA formula R1C1 do not accept calculation inside square brackets

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have quite old piece of VBA code and it has been working so far for Excel.
Now I have Office 365 and I tried to run this code and looks like it is not working - according to my investigation .FormulaR1C1 and/or Excel itself is not accepting calculation inside square brackets:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-7 + ((1 - 1) * 3)]);TRUE;False)
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the other Formula properties?

Comment: Try to add extra `()` inside square brackets

Comment: @Teamothy - adding ```()``` not working. Even excel not accept this.

Comment: Did it used to work? On what Excel version? Because I tried in Excel 2007 and it is not working (Even a simplier `=RC[1+2]`)

Comment: @VincentG - yes it used to work. At least from VBA. I was using code with iteration:
```.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-" & 7 + ((i - 1) * 3) & ...```
I am not sure if Excel itself allow for direct use of such notification in specific cell but for sure VBA code works fine.

Comment: That is valid VBA code.  But I do not believe it is valid on a worksheet to have math operations within the `RC[…]` brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, valid code would be, as you showed in a comment:

```
R.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[" & 1 + 6 & "]"
```

That is because the formula is reduced to a valid value before being written into the worksheet.

To do this directly in on the Excel worksheet you use the same method, but it also requires use of the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT("RC[" & 1+6 & "]",FALSE)
```